# Getting Office365 working with CFEXCHANGECONNECTION

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, office365

I couldn't find much useful information on opening a `CFEXCHANGE` connection to Office365. After some playing around I got it to work. I am posting this here for informational purposes as it might be useful for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the need to specify `serverversion="2010"` this will only work on CF10.

To establish a connection use the following code:

```
<cfexchangeConnection 
    action="open" 
    username ="#emailAddressForOffice365User#" 
    password="#passwordForOffice365User#"
    server="outlook.office365.com" 
    protocol="https"
    connection="myExchangeConnection"
    serverversion="2010">
```

The Office365 account I connected to had the settings which were set when it was created (i.e. I did not have to change any account settings for this to work).

Comment: Hi - How can/should this be updated for CF11? Does/can this also grab Calendar info?

Comment: You can use the `cfexchangecalendar` tag to access Office365 calendars after establishing the connection as shown above. The only change to the ColdFusion Exchange functionality in CF11 appears to be the addition of some extra attributes to the `cfexchangecalendar` tag (see https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfexchangecalendar).